# How can I show mysql locks?

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to show all the locks that are active in a mysql database?

Comment: You can query INNODB_LOCK_WAITS and INNODB_LOCKS tables.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

See Marko's link for InnoDB tables and the caveats.

For MyISAM, there isn't a dead easy "this is the offending query" solution. You should always start with a processlist. But be sure to include the full keyword so that the printed queries aren't truncated:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

This will show you a list of all current processes, their SQL query and state. Now usually if a single query is causing many others to lock then it should be easy to identify. The affected queries will have a status of `Locked` and the offending query will be sitting out by itself, possibly waiting for something intensive, like a temporary table.

If it's not obvious then you will have to use your powers of SQL deduction to determine which piece of offending SQL may be the cause of your woes.

Comment: what I run this but there are so many rows that I cant reach the top after it finishes?

Comment: @Dan Carley When a query is waiting for execution because the row it's meant to operate is locked by another transaction - the processlist shows 'updating' in the processlist not 'locked' in the MySQL (v5.7) instance. I'm not sure if I'm seeing 'locked' status even through the row is locked.

Comment: @VishnuPedireddi yeah, that's my experience. IMO the lock detection is broken on MySQL. There should be a lock wait event and status should be show waiting for a lock. On all other major relational databases Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 there are specfic lock waits. on MySQL it is hidden under wait/io/sql/table/handler  which also covers CPU reading buffers, I/O waiting for buffers and row level locking!

Answer (score 54):

If you use InnoDB and need to check running queries I recommend

`show engine innodb status;`

as mentioned in Marko's link. This will give you the locking query, how many rows/tables are locked by it etc. Look under TRANSACTIONS.

The problem with using `SHOW PROCESSLIST` is that you won't see the locks unless other queries are queueing up.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It will have a section for "LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK"

Comment: ``show engine innodb status \G`` for smaller screens

Answer (score 43):

Try [`SHOW OPEN TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-open-tables.html):

```
show open tables where In_Use > 0 ;
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to identify in use locks immediately especially if you have multiple databases and hundreds of connections.

Answer (score 37):

None of the answers can show all the locks that are currently held.

Do this e.g. in mysql in a terminal.

```
start transaction;
update someTable set name="foobar" where ID=1234;
-- but no rollback or commit - just let it sit there
```

Clearly the transaction above holds a lock, because the transaction is still active. But no query is going on right now and nobody is waiting for a lock anywhere (yet at least).

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS` is empty, which makes sense given the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-table.html), because there is only one transaction and currently nobody waiting for any locks. Also `INNODB_LOCKS` is deprecated anyway.

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` is useless: `someTable` is not mentioned at all

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` is empty, because the culprit is not actually running a query right now.

You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX`, `performance_schema.events_statements_history` and `performance_schema.threads` to extract the queries that any active transactions have executed in the past as outlined in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549264/how-to-troubleshoot-mysql-error-1205-hy000-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-r/53549265#53549265), but I haven't come across any way to see that `someTable` is locked in the above scenario.

The suggestions in the other answers so far won't help at least.

Disclaimer: I don't have innotop installed and I didn't bother. Perhaps that *could* work.

Comment: I was just planning to write a question specifically about this scenario (start transaction, run update, and wait), and then I noticed your answer. I have this problem in production. I had the idea to detect a "stuck" lock in code when getting the "Lock wait timeout exceeded" error, and then do two things at the same time: re-run the query, and run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS (from the other thread or process, on a second connection). But I would love to have a simpler way...

Comment: I am no expert on this, but the example transaction is not dependent on anything, so why would it hold a lock? It will only require a short lock during commit to do the write. You need for example `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to explicitly lock.

Comment: @MattiasWallin `SELECT FOR UPDATE` will create a lock, because `SELECT` otherwise wouldn't. But `UPDATE` also creates a lock until the transaction is rolled back or submitted. (I'm no expert either)

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch I tried it, and you are correct. Other `UPDATE` gets blocked, so there _is_ a lock. Also `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` hints about a lock: `2 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 1 row lock(s)`. But as you already stated, nothing about _what_ is locked.. :-(

Comment: This is the only answer I needed to know. Thank you for doing the research. I wasn't sure if the dataset in my application would cache it's own copy in memory and then "commits" everything all at once. Everything get's pushed to the database immediately. A simple commit command will then process all the cached (transactional) data in the database.

Answer (score 10):

**[Reference taken from this post.](http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/02/mysql-script-to-identify-the-locks-and-blocking-transactions/)**

You can use below script:

```
SELECT 
    pl.id
    ,pl.user
    ,pl.state
    ,it.trx_id 
    ,it.trx_mysql_thread_id 
    ,it.trx_query AS query
    ,it.trx_id AS blocking_trx_id
    ,it.trx_mysql_thread_id AS blocking_thread
    ,it.trx_query AS blocking_query
FROM information_schema.processlist AS pl 
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_trx AS it
    ON pl.id = it.trx_mysql_thread_id
INNER JOIN information_schema.innodb_lock_waits AS ilw
    ON it.trx_id = ilw.requesting_trx_id 
        AND it.trx_id = ilw.blocking_trx_id
```

Comment: On MySQL 5.7: `Warning (Code 1681): 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCK_WAITS' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.`

Answer (score 7):

Using this command

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

will show all process currently running, including process that has acquired lock on tables.

Comment: That doesn't says which locks on which table.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK there's still no native way in MYSQL, but I use [innotop](https://web.archive.org/web/20181108030406/https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/02/innotop-mysql-innodb-monitor/). It's free and has plenty of other functionality as well.

Also see [this link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks) for more information on using the innotop tool.

Answer (score 3):

`show engine innodb status;` is the way to do this with innodb, but there's an extra step: `SET GLOBAL innodb_status_output_locks=ON;` first, per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-enabling-monitors.html